# Autofill column across dynamic start

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

I am trying to write a code to autofill the final column in a worksheet to the right x times.

I have the code which will pick up the last column :

```
 With ActiveSheet
 LC = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 End With
 Columns(LC).Select
```

and also code that would autofill across if I specify which specific columns

```
 Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Columns("BE:BQ"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

What I am struggling with is how to replace the columns "BE:BQ" with the required code which is linked to the original Last Column (LC).
Ideally I would like it to autofill across to add, say 10, new columns. Do you have any advice?

Ideally I would like the code to cycle through all the worksheets in my workbook - but this is probably a bit advanced for me!

Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE**

Thank you for your suggested comments. I have amended the code as below. This firstly appeared to work perfectly. However, I have since come across two issues.

**Issue 1** - on some sheets when it fills across a date field which is in row 3 does not fill. It just copies across the date exactly the same as the one in the last row (i.e. 01/06/2017 but is displayed as Jun-17). I would like this to fill across a month at a time.

**Issue 2** - in row 2 there is a date which is the last day of the pervious month. This is currently entered manually but as I have developed the macro I would like this to be changed to a formula equal to date in the cell below minus 1 day. I tried to do this using the following formula but it went completely awry!

```
sht.Cells(2, LC).Formula = "=" & Cells(3, LC) & "-1"
```

Any advice on how to fix these two issues would be most appreciated.

Comment: One approach is `cells(1,LC).resize(,10).entirecolumn.autofill` but do you really want to fill the whole column (and selecting is not usually advisable or necessary).

Comment: It doesn't need to be - I could add in a last row calculation and autofill across that way. How would the VBA be adjusted for that assuming LR is the calculated last row?

Comment: please move your answer to an actual answer, instead of editing your question with the answer, then mark the answer as accepted after an allotted time as passed. This makes it easier for other users to find the answer coming forward.\

Comment: @ScottHoltzman thank you & have updated the Answer but I have found a couple of issues since I have started using the code. So have updated the question above.

Comment: I've suggested an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim LC As Integer
Dim LR As Long

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

With ActiveSheet
    LC = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, LC).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Range(Cells(1, LC), Cells(LR, LC)).Select

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1, LC), Cells(LR, LC + 10)),Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm not sure about the A2 bit as the code suggests the autofill starts at row 3 but can jus replace 3 with 2 in the code if it should also be included.

```
Sub x()

Dim LC As Long, LR As Long, ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
        LC = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range(.Cells(3, LC), .Cells(LR, LC)).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(3, LC), .Cells(LR, LC + 10)), Type:=xlFillDefault
        .Cells(3, LC).AutoFill Destination:=.Cells(3, LC).Resize(, 10), Type:=xlFillMonths
        .Range("A2").Formula = "=A3-1"
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```